# Send parameter between applications in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, get, web-parts

I'm working on Sharepoint 2013, developing a Sharepoint-hosted app (CSOM and javaScript).

I'm trying to get a webpart to pass a parameter to a web application both created by me.

This is the link defined of the application i'm trying to pass a parameter to:

https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/folder/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id=zb098ab4%2D25bd%2D432c%2D81fc%2D69630d059f1a&dev_site_list=1

The problem, is that "appredirect.aspx" clears any parameter I send through a get request.
For example: &variable='value'.

I read that it was possible to add to parameter using &redirect_uri={URL} , but even using it, parameter gets lost through the intervention of appredirect.aspx

Is there a way to pass a parameter from a web part to another sharepoint application?
Keep in mind the application, is not another web part on the same page.

Thanks in advance.